# $\mu$ Catalised fusion energy

Tags: energy, particle-physics, fusion, cold-fusion

How can i calculate the energy that i get from $\mu$ fusion. I want to know how much energy can we get from a deuteriom-triton-muon fusion.

I know that it comes from the masses being different. So i can use the famous $E=mc^2+p^2c^2$ equation to get the energy from a deuteron $1875 \dfrac{MeV}{c^2}$, and a tritium $2809\dfrac{MeV}{c^2}$.

From the fusion we get an $\alpha $ particle which mass is $3727.4 \dfrac{MeV}{c^2}$ and a fast moving neutron $939.56563 \dfrac{MeV}{c^2}$

So i can use $1875 MeV+2809MeV=3727.4 MeV+939.56563 MeV+ Extra \hspace{2mm} energy$
And i get $Extra energy=17.6 MeV$

Is this a correct calculation?
Why dont i have to use the $(pc)^2$ part?

Comment: Check the dimensions on your equation for energy.

Answer (score 0):

The deueterium-tritium fusion cross section has a maximum at a centre of mass energy of around 200 keV. See for example this plot:

[image: Cross section]

([source](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Cross-section-of-different-fusion-reactions-The-Deuterium-Tritium-reaction-has-a_fig1_344176478))

This energy is small compared to the approximately 5 GeV rest mass energy of the deuteron and tritium nucleus. That means to a good approximation we can simply ignore the kinetic energy of the nuclei i.e. set $p = 0$. Then your equation for the energy simplifies to the well know equation $E=mc^2$ and the calculation proceeds as you have done.

Your result, $17.6$ MeV agrees with [the figure quoted by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuterium%E2%80%93tritium_fusion).

Comment: Well, if you do it in the center of mass frame you have by definition eliminated the total momentum from consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, because the momentum of the particles is small compared to their rest mass energy.

Forget about the $(pc)^2$ term in the equations for a moment and assume we can do the whole calculation simply using $E = mc^2$. In doing so, you already correctly showed that the DT reaction leads to a 'left-over' energy of 17.6 MeV due to the mass difference of the before and after the reaction. This resulting 17.6 MeV of energy will be divided over the two resulting particles as *kinetic* energy. Because of conservation of momentum, the kinetic energy both particles receive is the (inverse) fraction of their masses. That is, the helium particle has 4/5ths of the mass of the resulting particles (5 total nucleons, 4 in the $\alpha$-particle and 1 in the neutron) and the neutron 1/5th, so the neutron gets 4/5ths of the energy (14.1 MeV) and the $\alpha$-particle gets (1/5th of 17.6 MeV) 3.5 MeV. The neutron has a mass of approximately 939 MeV/c$^2$, so the 14.1 MeV of kinetic energy it gains is only about 1.5% of its rest mass energy, which is only a small correction in the calculations that's not even going to show up if you write your energies to only three significant digits (e.g. 17.6). The $\alpha$-particle gets even less energy over a higher mass, so the percentage is even smaller. If you compute the Lorentz factor correction it is the same ($\gamma \approx 1.015$).

Now, if you wanted to do this to a higher precision than three digits, you might want to factor in the momentum term, especially for the neutron.